# asp.net update panel create new dropdownbox

Tags: asp.net, combobox, updatepanel, dropdownbox

I have a problem with asp.net panel I want to modify a dropdownbox datasource selectcommand when change index of an other dropdownbox but every I change the new dropdownbox create
this my code:

```
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"  >
          <ContentTemplate>
              <asp:DropDownList ID="comboCountry" runat="server"   AutoPostBack="True"
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="comboCountry_OnSelectedIndexChanged"
                    DataTextField="country_name" DataValueField="country_id">

                  </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:JobsConnectionString %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [country]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </td>
             </tr>
            <tr class="trwidth">
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="comboCity" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"  
                    DataTextField="city_name" DataValueField="location_id">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:JobsConnectionString %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [location]"></asp:SqlDataSource> 
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

code behind:

```
protected void comboCountry_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [location] where [country_id]=" + comboCountry.SelectedValue;            
       // SqlDataSource2.DataBind();
        comboCity.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more about what the problem is? What result do you get and what result do you want?

Comment: when I change the index of combobox (comboCountry) it should invoke method comboCountry_OnSelectedIndexChanged and change datasource selectcommand for SqlDataSource2 and then the combobox(comboCity) items should be updated but instead of updating combobox(comboCity) items I get new combobox that contain new items.

Comment: What do you mean by "new items"?

Comment: I mean this <Items></Items>

Answer (score 0):

Select the value for country_code in your first dromp down and then bind the second dropdown parameter to the first drowpdown. then set auto post back on the first dropdown to true and the the second dropdown will render with the results.